# Structuremap Open Generic named instances

Tags: c#, generics, structuremap, named-instance

I must do the following:

```
var someType = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance("myNamedInstance");
```

where someType can be any implementation of ICommand.

so I registered some of them:

```
For(typeof(ICommand<>)).Use(typeof(Command1)).Named("myNamedInstance1");
For(typeof(ICommand<>)).Use(typeof(Command2)).Named("myNamedInstance2");
```

is there a way to do this in StructureMap, because GetNamedInstance requires the type parameter which I don3t know until runtime.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(For this, I'm assuming *you* created `ICommand<T>`)

This doesn't actually make any sense...  think of the line:

```
//where aString is either myNamedInstance1 or myNamedInstance2
var someType = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance(aString);
```

Now assume that you are not going to use `var`, and instead the actual type.  What would you put there that could compile? That is, what type can someType possibly be other than `object`?

Also, remember that `ICommand<string>` and `ICommand<int>` are both constructed types from `ICommand<T>`, but are not otherwise related - they have no common base type other than `object`.

If you don't the type until runtime, generics are not going to help a bunch - instead make your `ICommand<T>` inherit from some common interface - like `ICommandBase` - that has the methods you actually need.

However, if you just don't know the type *in that method*, you can push the unknown "up" in the compile by making the method containing that generic:

```
public void Execute<T>( string commandName)
{        
    var someType = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<ICommand<T>>(commandName);
    someType.Execute();
}
```

Now the caller of execute needs the type param... but again you could push that up.  Notice that eventually you'll need the type parameter.